# Set Match Tolerance for Multiple Matches using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to find all occurrences of a smaller image within a larger image. Is there a way to set the tolerance level of the match so I could match everything that was at least a 90% match or something like that?

Here's my code right now:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import cv
import numpy as np

method = cv.CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED

small_image = cv2.imread('small_image.jpg')
large_image = cv2.imread('large_image.jpg')

height,width = small_image.shape[:2]

result = cv2.matchTemplate(large_image, small_image, method)
result2 = np.reshape(result, result.shape[0]*result.shape[1])
sort = np.argsort(result2)

for i in range(50):
    (y1, x1) = np.unravel_index(sort[i], result.shape)
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    print '%s: (%s, %s) to (%s, %s)' % (i, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    cv2.rectangle(large_image, (x1-3,y1-3), (x2+3,y2+3), (0,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('output',large_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> After the function finishes the comparison, the best matches can be found as global minimums (when CV_TM_SQDIFF was used) or maximums (when CV_TM_CCORR or CV_TM_CCOEFF was used) using the minMaxLoc() function

You can use `minMaxLoc()` to do this threshholding for you.

[Here is a tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) - the key point is below:

```
   minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

  /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
  if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    { matchLoc = minLoc; }
  else
    { matchLoc = maxLoc; }
```

Edit: From comment:

> The solution you've given seems to only give SINGLE matches. The issue is that I need to be able to set tolerance for MULTIPLE matches. Am I missing something?

Sort of, like I said, you need to use this value as a threshold. [This](http://samwize.com/2013/06/09/using-opencv-to-match-template-multiple-times/) tutorial shows you how to use that threshold value in order to match for **multiple** occurrences.

It uses minMaxLoc, then it floodFills the image, then repeats.

Comment: Will that return multiple matches?

Comment: The solution you've given seems to only give SINGLE matches. The issue is that I need to be able to set tolerance for MULTIPLE matches. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry. I'm sure that makes a lot of sense to somebody really familiar with Python and/or OpenCV. Both are pretty new to me. From this AND the tutorial, I still don't see where I set the threshold or pull multiple results.

Comment: this doesn't work for python, those are the c++ arguments